# Перестало работать подменю

Tags: modx, меню

Здравствуйте, уважаемые. Помогите, пожалуйста, в данной проблеме.

Начну по порядку. У нашей компании есть сайт, панель управления сайтом `MODx`.
Я как сотрудник занимаюсь наполнением сайта контентом, заполняю каталог товаров. Это меню раньше выглядело вот так:

```
Каталог товаров

    Кабельно-проводниковые изделия
          Провод 
          Кабель 
          Кабель с изоляцией из сшитого полиэтилена 
    Системы прокладки кабеля
    Низковольтное оборудование
    Электроустановочные изделия
    Светильники
    Источники света
    Системы молниезащиты
    Высоковольтное оборудование
```

Заполнял я Кабельно-проводниковые изделия, все было нормально. Потом решил заполнить страницу "Продукция". Думал поставить такие же силки, что и в Каталоге товаров, только еще добавить картинок, чтоб было красиво. После обновления перестало работать подменю. Когда я нажимаю на "Кабельно-проводниковые изделия", должно появиться

```
Провод 
  Кабель 
  Кабель с изоляцией из сшитого полиэтилена
```

А его нет. У панели управления сайтом оно есть. И статьи, которые я добавлял тоже.
[image: alt image]

А вот на самом сайте его нет:

[image: alt image]

Помогите, пожалуйста, это исправить.

Comment: @s83maloy, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.  
@s83maloy, Согласно правилам форума, вам нужно научится __разделять приложения между собой точками, новые предложения начинать с Большой буквы, а так же поставить хоть одну запятую__.

Comment: Самое интересное что у вас в Англоязычной версий работает а в Русской нет.
Консоль ничего не показывает , с ModX не знаком , но Я предполагаю что Вы удалили содержимое или пункты подменю.

Comment: Обращайтесь на почту

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, здесь за построение меню отвечает самописный сниппет. Этот сниппет не учитывает глубину иерархии документов. Скорее всего, рассчитан на максимум 3 вложенности. Говорю не точно, т.к. не вижу сниппета построения меню.

Comment: а где посмотреть этот снипет?

Comment: Элементы/управление элементами/сниппеты

Но что бы узнать какой именно сниппет строит меню, нужно в шаблоне глянуть под каким именем сниппет

Comment: у шаблоне посмотрел там надпись [[MainTemplate]]
http://s50.radikal.ru/i127/1207/45/c72131e0f4f2.jpg 
отрыл сниппет MainTemplate там такой код  

    <?php
    if(in_array($modx->documentIdentifier, array(1,2,3)))
    {
         echo '{{index_tpl}}';
    }
    else
    {
          echo '{{pages_tpl}}';
    }
    ?>

http://s017.radikal.ru/i419/1207/ba/85e658865dba.jpg
ой чувствую что там что то не то. выручай Артемка я в долгу не останусь. Артем добавь меня пожалуйста у скайп s84maloy. может ты сможешь посмотреть через TeamViewer я роботу оплачу.